# Datetime type conversion in SQL

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am getting data from some external datasource and need to store in SQL server table. But one filed in it is Datetime. But I am getting that datetime field as Varchar format, and now in my SQL table I need to save it as DateTime datatype.

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,[Date_time],03)
```

-- This code work in my Development Environment but not in Production.

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,[Date_time],120)
```

-- This code work in my Production but not in development.

This make my life difficult to transfer code from development to Production since I have to make changes in tested code.

Please note that I am using SQL server 2008 R2.

Is there anyway that I can make code similar? I cannot change the culture and language on both server since many other applications are deployed there and it might break existing application in both server.

Comment: Why would your production and development environments have different cultures?  Something is amiss.

Comment: I am guessing you have some .net code consuming the data from the external source... I am not really familiar with the .net way of things but ur code apparently needs some conditional statement depending on the environment its running on. You could try issuing a select @@Version SQL and depending on what you get back have a conditional statement to handle the different environments. Here is some more info on it- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177512.aspx ---Hope this helps.

Comment: The version of SQL is same but as I told, the cultures are different so need to use different style of conversion. I have raise this issue to my Manager that why both the environment has different cultures? but I even have to try myself to find a way to solve this issue..

Comment: Hi TMNT2014, I am not pulling data from .net. But using openquery in SQL to pull it. All data pulled in SQL is ok but only have problem with this Datetime filed due to different culture in both server. The solution what you have told me thats what I have even used. But want to check if there is any standard way to solve this issue, instead of writing if else condition based on server name. Since in long run the server can change and codes will start breaking. Hope you understand my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You seem to have a standardization issue ... where you cant standardize ur environments but need your code to be standardized. If you do find a standard way to solve this issue, kindly let me know.. Best of luck

Comment: Is there anyway I can get SQL Server Culture Info by writing query?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for your problem would be to provide a feature that calculates (or defines) the correct style for each environment.  This simplest option would be a user-defined function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCustomDateStyle]()
RETURN int AS
BEGIN
  RETURN 3 # Or 120, in the other environment
END
```

Which can be used in every environment thus:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, [Date_Time], fnCustomDateStyle())
```

Comment: I am using the same method from past. But was looking if there is any another standard way. Bcoz this code I need to change when there is change in Server Name.

Comment: Is there anyway I can get SQL Server Culture Info by writing sql query?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a `SET` statement to override the date format, something like this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, [Date_Time], 120);
```

As long as you include this code in your stored procedure/query on both environments, this should be fine. You may want to read up about this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).